# vncserver exited too early

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have a Ubuntu 21.10 headless and I need to connect to it using remote desktop. When I attempt to start using `vncserver`command I get the below too early exit code

```
hd2900@hd2900:~/.vnc$ vncserver

New Xtigervnc server 'hd2900:1 (hd2900)' on port 5901 for display :1.
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/hd2900/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.


=================== tail /home/hd2900/.vnc/hd2900:5901.log ===================
==============================================================================

Session startup via '/home/hd2900/.vnc/xstartup' cleanly exited too early (< 3 seconds)!

Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
The X session cleanly exited!
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 10156... success!
hd2900@hd2900:~/.vnc$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

My xstartup file is configured as

```sh
cat xstartup 
#!/bin/sh
# Start Gnome 3 Desktop 
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

The VNC was set up by

```
apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
apt install tigervnc-standalone-server
```

Then I set up the password using `vncpasswd` command followed by `vncserver` to command to launch the server.

Comment: Does `tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/gnome-session` work? I use XFCE, and encountered the same error. `tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xfce4-session` worked for me

Answer (score 12):

```
tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

will work. Indeed all you need to do is to remove **&** from the last line:

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
```

Looks like newer versions of tigervncserver expects the ~/.vnc/xstartup (or ~/.vnc/Xtigervnc-session) script to stay in foreground. (I am on Ubuntu 21.10 and the ending & is the problem. On 20.04LTS the ending & is not an issue.)